# How can I output the data to csv after producing data

Tags: python, django

Currently, my application is to select the stock data, then analyzing it by using another python script and output the result(in JSON format).
Now I would like to add a button to output the result(w_df_split) to CSV, then when the user clicks the button and download the csv file.
But I am stuck in how to return the output CSV function in this view.

views.py:

```
def efficient_frontier_select(request):
    user_holding = Position.objects.filter(created_by = request.user)
    selected_stock = None
    
    w_df_split = None
   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_stock = request.POST.getlist('stock_symbol')
        ta, tb, tc = ef.combination_frontier(selected_stock)
        fy_df, fx_df, w_df, fxfy_df, ef_df = ef.transform_frontier_todf(ta,tb,tc, selected_stock)
        w_df_split = json.loads(ef.json_format_split(w_df))

    context = {
        'w_df_split' : w_df_split,  
    }
    
    return render(request, 'portfolio/efficient_frontier.html', context)
```

Comment: check this out: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345336/save-results-to-csv-file-with-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345336/save-results-to-csv-file-with-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save results to csv file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345336/save-results-to-csv-file-with-python)

Comment: I edited.. sorry for the not clear question..
Now I would like to add a button to output the result(w_df_split) to CSV, then when the user clicks the button and download the csv file. But I am stuck in how to return the output CSV function in this view.

Answer (score 0):

Asumming df is a dataframe, you you could use pandas's `df.to_csv()`. Like that: `csv_data = w_df.to_csv()`. You could do the same to json with `w_df.to_json()`

Comment: I try this, but df.to_csv() is to output the string in Django when I am applying this to button.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update!
[Django view design - export CSV from user-generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61816299/django-view-design-export-csv-from-user-generated-content)

This works by setting the hidden input field to store the JSON data.